# How to show icons a indication of progress?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to add a product activity which contains 4 steps and I want to show progress bar with icons as indicators.

[image]

This is the UI design

Comment: change the icon `color and line color` while replacing your fragment

Comment: sir thats not an answer , i need to include those items in the progress bar